# How to import only one Tkinter widget method instead of a whole package?

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I am writing a python application using tkinter. One of my classes only uses the delete method on an Entry widget object. I wanted to know if there was a way to only import that method instead of importing the entire package.

I have tried looking around online and have tried different things, but I have not had much luck as of yet.

I am finding the online documentation for the standard python libraries to be very unclear and confusing.

Comment: If the stdlib's docs are unclear then perhaps you could start with [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tut) first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to import only one method of a widget, or only one method of any class. When you import a class you get the whole class.

Why do you think it would be advantageous to import only one method? If you're concerned about memory consumption, don't be.

Comment: Thank you, it was mostly out of curiosity. I guess I was just a little bit confused by the syntax and I thought I was actually doing something else. Thanks for clarifying.